# сумма 2-х запросов AJAX

Tags: ajax

есть 2-ой AJAX запрос нужно чтоб 
в `id sum_cash` получить разницу

```
$('#inc_total').html(sum)-$('#out_total').html(sum1)
```

Вот код:

```
<input class='plmn' id="date1" type='date' name='date' onchange="date1()">
<input class='plmn' id="date2" type='date' name='date'  onchange="date1() value="<?php $date=date("Y-m-d"); echo $date?>" required>

                    <script>                        
                        function date1(){
                            var date1=document.getElementById("date1").value;
                            var date2=document.getElementById("date2").value;

                            $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "account_incoming.php",
                                    data: {date1:date1, date2:date2},
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    success: function(data) { 
                                        $("#one").empty();      
                                        $("#inc_total").empty();        
                                        $.each(data.incoming, function() {
                                            $("#one").append("<tr><td id='cat_name'>" + this.inc_cat_name + "</td><td id='cash'>" + this.totalinc_cash + "</td></tr>");

                                             var sum = 0;
                                            $('#one tr').each(function(){
                                                sum+=parseInt($('#cash', this).text());
                                            });
                                        $('#inc_total').html(sum);                                  
                                        });

                                        }

                                    })

                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "account_output.php",
                                    data: {date1:date1, date2:date2},
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    success: function(data) { 
                                        $("#two").empty();      
                                        $("#out_total").empty();

                                        $.each(data.output, function() {
                                            $("#two").append("<tr><td id='cat_name'>" + this.out_cat_name + "</td><td id='cash1'>" + this.totalout_cash + "</td></tr>");
                                         var sum1 = 0; 
                                            $('#two tr').each(function(){
                                                sum1+=parseInt($('#cash1', this).text());
                                            });
                                            $('#out_total').html(sum1); 

                                        })

                                    }

                                }); 

                        }
```

Comment: А что вам мешает перед запросами объявить переменные и после выполнения запросов - их сложить???

Comment: Самое простое - перенести второй AJAX-запрос в `success` первого.

Comment: А куда складывать результаты?

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

```
function date1(){
  ...
  var d1 = $.ajax({...});
  var d2 = $.ajax({...}); 

  $.when(d1, d2).done(function() {
    var raznica = +$('#inc_total').html() - +$('#out_total').html();
  });
}
```